# Reopen question 439470: "What is the difference between Windows 8 Pro and Windows RT?"

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, reopen-request

> [What is the difference between Windows 8 and Windows RT?](https://superuser.com/questions/439470/what-is-the-difference-between-windows-8-pro-and-windows-rt)

How is this question *not constructive*?  I mean, I don't see how this would be a subjective question, let alone ["bad subjective"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)!  This question is not a shopping recommendation and asks for the technical differences between Windows 8 (Pro) and Windows RT.  These operating systems have significant differences, and the differences between Windows 8 and Windows RT are a potential source of confusion among many consumers.

In short, this question is objectively answerable.

Comment: I have a hard time seeing the problem myself right now. But I am sure you're aware that the parties involved in closing the question are reputable members of the community, so I wouldn't want to reopen it too hastily.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: I thought the same while I was reading the question and answers. However, there's a pretty detailed answer with 45 upvotes, from another reputable member. The same member has also a comment "We had actually been planning to make a question like this soon, since somebody was bound to wonder. You beat me to the punch!". So it sounds like it was a perfectly legit question according to him?

Comment: As said person... yes, I think it's an important question. There are significant differences between Windows 8 and Windows RT, which many people may not realize. I would hesitate to reopen it myself though since that might be viewed as a conflict of interest, but I don't think there's anything wrong with the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I voted to close a little too hastily on this one.  Looking back I must've been reading a little too quickly on the question and title and I sincerely apologize for closing it.  I've voted to reopen and urge others to do so as well (I've even commented on the question my opinions as well).

However, we **really** need to be careful about these types of questions.  Just as this is a perfectly legitimate one with an excellent answer, there are others [(here's a quick example)](https://superuser.com/questions/484359/whats-the-difference-between-these-asus-socket-1155-motherboards) that are out there which state "What's the difference between X and Y" and lead to terrible answers, and no knowledge to be gleaned from them.  This was my reasoning initially when voting to close.

*Also I would suggest adding answers (even just the top few) to the review systems to see how questions like this are being answered and therefore how they should be handled by reviewers*

---

It looks like the question has been [reopened now by 5 community votes](https://superuser.com/posts/439470/revisions).